# Can I use a single pthread mutex to lock/unlock many global variables?

Tags: c, multithreading, tcp, client-server, mutex

let's suppose we have a Client-Server application based on TCP/IP communication and multi-thread.

Let's suppose Server-side we have these three global variables:

```
char matrix[ROW][COLUMNS];
int isEmpty = 0;
float anotherDummyVariable;
```

If I declare a global pthread mutex as follows

```
pthread_mutex_t myMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

can I use this mutex to `lock` and `unlock` any of these three variables, as follows:

```
...somewhere in the code...
pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
isEmpty = 1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
```

and somewhere else...

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
matrix[ROW][COLUMNS]={0};
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
```

**or** should I declare three mutexes, one for each global variable to manage, as follows:

```
pthread_mutex_t matrixMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t isEmptyMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t anotherDummyVariableMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

and, somewhere in the code...

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&isEmptyMutex);
isEmpty = 1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&isEmptyMutex);
```

and somewhere else...

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&matrixMutex);
matrix[ROW][COLUMNS]={0};
pthread_mutex_unlock(&matrixMutex);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Using one mutex will work. However this is not optimal, as each time a variable is locked, all the others are locked as well.

Depending on the program, that may be necessary (if there are some dependencies between variable, one cannot be changed without the other). But if it is not, it's better to have one mutex per block of data / variable.

So, depending on the performance impact, and also, the algorithm, you might prefer to use multiple mutexes.

Taking an exemple,

```
int data[N]; 
int count = 0;              // number of items in data
```

we have `data` and `count` inter dependent.

```
void set(int arr, int size) { // add size items from arr to data
   ... 
   for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++) data[count++] = arr[i];
   ...
}
```

In this case it would be better to lock the whole function with one mutex (making a critical section), that protects data and count

```
   void set(int arr, int size) { // add size items from arr to data
       pthread_mutex_lock(dataaccess);
       ... 
       for(i=0 ; i<size ; i++) data[count++] = arr[i];
       ...
       pthread_mutex_unlock(dataaccess);
   }
```

Somewhere else having a function that checks `count` and reads `data[i]`

```
   int read(int i) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(dataaccess);
       ... 
       if (i >= count) { ...throw error }
       int res = data[i];
       ...
       pthread_mutex_unlock(dataaccess);
       return res;
   }
```